# Data View - differentiate multi-step and single-send journey

Tags: marketing-cloud

Has any one come across differentiating multi-step to single-send journeys in data view?
We currently have a requirement to pull the email engagement data and categorise ad-hoc vs journey.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Salesforce has not introduced any new filed in the journey data view that will differentiate this. Hence, the answer would be no.

Answer (score 1):

They both are tracked in the "normal" data views such as _sent, _click etc.
They also both are tracked in the "journey" data views _journey and _journeyActivity.

That being said, there is no journey typisation in those data views, and there are no other data views that relate to journeys. Which implies that you'll best differentiate by either the journey name (you could think of a naming convention) or the email activity as described here:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_query_journey_builder_sends_by_email_across_versions.htm&type=5